# Is this outdoor light wiring correct?

Tags: electrical, lighting, exterior

I have an outdoor light that isn't working. I've removed and tested it indoors. It works fine and the bulb is fine.

The wiring that comes from the house consists of two twin-and-earth cables. Power is on the same circuit as the indoor ceiling lights.

Please excuse my amateur diagram. The wiring into the lamp looks like this, with the two incoming cables at the top, lamp connections at the bottom:

```
   | | |     | | |
   | | |     | | |
X__| | |_____| | |__X
     |    |    |
     |    |    |
     ο    ο    ο
     L    E    N
```

- The earths are entwined and wired into the lamp.
- The live input is taken from one cable, and neutral from the other.
- The other two wires (X) go nowhere, but may have come loose!
- I presume one cable goes to the switch, but I can't be sure.

Is this wiring correct? I inherited it when I moved into the house, but it did work once upon a time.

**Is there anything incorrect/unsafe about this wiring that could have stopped the light working?**

---

Possible solution:

If the two loose wires have come apart, and assuming one cable goes to the switch. I am wondering if the following is correct. Below the loose ends (previously marked X) are connected so they complete the circuit via the switch (S).

```
    (S)   
   o   o     L E N
   | E |     | | |
   | | |     | | |
   | | |     | | |
   | | +--X--+ | |
   | +----+----+ |
   |      |      | 
   +---o  ο  o---+   
       L  E  N
```

Comment: That certainly doesn't _look_ right, but maybe someone with more UK experience will have a better idea.  This is near London?

Comment: I am in London, yes.

Comment: I added some more info. Do you think the two dead ends (X) have come apart and should be connected?

Comment: Normally, one cable comes into the box and another cable leaves to go to the next box or to connect to a switch.  When it goes to a new box, all the N's are connected together, all the Es together and all the Ls together.  They wouldn't be connected to each other as in your diagram.  If the second cable was for a switch the pattern would be a little different, but I still wouldn't expect to have two loose wires left over.

Comment: That makes sense. The second cable must go to the switch then. I'll look at updating my diagram with fewer assumptions

Comment: You gave me the hint I needed by mentioning the switch. I think the two loose ends have come apart. Does my solution look correct?

Comment: It's plausible.  You can check the continuity of the L and N wires on that left cable to see if the switch connects them when it's on.  You can check voltage between the L and N on the right cable when the power is on to verify that is the "incoming" wire.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I'll run those tests tomorrow.

Comment: Can you post an actual photo of the ceiling rose?

Comment: It's not a ceiling rose. It's an outside light. I would have posted a picture of the wiring, but it's a total mess

Comment: My idea is that you have to splice the two "dead ends" to close the switch loop. (the switch usually breaks only the phase, so it needs only two active wires one "permanent phase" and the other that is "switched") so the second scheme, in my opinion, should work.

Comment: Working. Thanks all for your input

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to clues from folks in the comments I solved this by simply connecting the two dead ends together to form the switch loop. They had obviously come loose inside the lamp (possibly through wiggling of cable when lamp angle changed).

With these ends connected, the wall switch ON and power OFF I could confirm conductivity between the previously loose end and the live terminal on the lamp. This gave me the confidence that one of the cables indeed went to the switch and identified the live wire. (no useful colours to go by).

With power ON I could confirm 240V between the live wire and the neutral connection  on the lamp, and with the switch ON also I confirmed 240V flowing between the L+N terminals on the lamp and the bulb contacts.

Light now works. Thanks all commenters.